# jssor fixed pixel dimensions requirement

Tags: jssor

What is the rational behind jssor to require all fixed dimensions in pixel? This could be clearly more user friendly if jssor library gets parent dimensions from available JS api. Often we would like something to be relative to the parent without dealing with scaling and such. Outer and inner container report problems if any value is not in pixels. This is really the only and biggest issue for me in otherwise great library. It should be more responsive by nature, without manual scaling methods.

Answer (score 0):

The responsive code makes the slider to fit any size. It will fit parent width in following manner,

```
//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales
//while window resizes
function ScaleSlider() {
    var parentWidth = $('#slider1_container').parent().width();
    if (parentWidth) {
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
    }
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
//Scale slider after document ready
ScaleSlider();

//Scale slider while window load/resize/orientationchange.
$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
```

Comment: I have tried this already. Didn't dig into the code yet, but seem like this kind of scaling is using transformation, because as a result I get "scaled-out" images. Should this actually recalculate all elements or does it use transformation?

Comment: It uses transform which leads best performance other than recalculation for all elements.